# Can you get all positive numbers in python?

Tags: python

So I am playing around in python and I thought:

"Is there a built in list or function that already has infinite numbers, if not how could I build one?"

I did some research and found...
Nothing
That is why I am here!
If you don't know what I mean it would be this but infinite:

`b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

etc;

If there is please tell me! Thank you!
Edit: Thank you!

Comment: A list of infinite numbers would require infinite memory. Why do you need a list of all positive numbers? What are you actually trying *to do with it?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own infinite list using a generator function without any module imports.

```
def infinite_list():
    n = 1
    while True:
         yield n
         n += 1

my_list = infinite_list()
```

Each time you want the next number call the next method:

```
next(my_list)
```

You can also iterate over it but it will, of course, be an infinite loop:

```
for elem in my_list:
    //infinite loop
```

Comment: Note: This is not an infinite *list* (so the name is a bit misleading), and it's doing exactly what `itertools.count(1)` would do, but slower. Use `itertools.count`, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.count` produces an iterator over arbitrary, infinite numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). It's not a sequence (you can't index it, you can only iterate each instance once), but you can keep going forever.

Actually running it to completion will take infinite time of course, so it's typically paired with something that limits it, e.g. `itertools.islice`, `zip`-ing with a finite iterable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import count

for i in count(1):
    print(i)
```

its infinite though so it might take a while to run